# Hooks and Redux / useEffect chatbot

Tags: reactjs, redux

Hello I have a problem I have a state that I use to hide a typing animation from the chat
but for some reason the animation is picking up on all messages when the state is true

**action:**

```
     //action user send message
    export const sendMessage = text => ({
      type: ON_MESSAGE,
      text,
    });
//action user wait bot response
    export const wait_anwser = () => ({
      type: WAIT_AWNSER,
    });
//action bot send response
    export const botMessage = text => ({
      type: BOT_MESSAGE,
      text,
    });
//action end wait response   
    export const wait_end = () => ({
      type: WAIT_END
    });

    export const checkMessage = text => {
      return dispatch => {
        dispatch(sendMessage(text));
        dispatch(wait_anwser());
        dispatch(botMessage(verify(text)));
      };
    };
```

**redux:**

```
const initalState = {
  messages: [],
  waitResponse: false,
  bot: false,
};

const messageReducer = (state = initalState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ON_MESSAGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        messages: [
          ...state.messages,
          {
            type: 'user',
            text: action.text,
            date: moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY-h:mm:ss'),
          },
        ],
      };

    case BOT_MESSAGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        messages: [
          ...state.messages,
          {
            type: 'bot',
            text: action.text,
            date: moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY-h:mm:ss'),
          },
        ],
      };
    case WAIT_AWNSER:
      return {
        ...state,
        waitResponse: true,
      };
    case WAIT_END: 
    return {
      ...state,
      waitResponse: false,
    };
    default:
      return state;
  }
```

jsx:

```
const Chat = props => {
  //Redux
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const ChatReducer = useSelector(state => state.Chat);
  const WidgetReducer = useSelector(state => state.WidgetStatus.widgetStatus);
  const [isTyping, setIsTyping] = useState(false);
  const [visibleText, setVisibleText] = useState(['']);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(ChatReducer.waitResponse === true){
      setIsTyping(true);
    }
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      setIsTyping(false);
      dispatch(wait_end());
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }, [ChatReducer.waitResponse]);

 return (
 <Styled.ChatBox widget={WidgetReducer}>
 <Styled.ChatLog>
         /*here map my state messages*/
        {ChatReducer.messages.map((rowData, index) =>
        /*here is the user messages*/
          rowData.type === 'user' ? (
            <Styled.MessageFlexColumn key={index}>
              <Styled.MessageWrapper user={true}>
                <Styled.ChatMessage user={true}>
                  {rowData.text}
                </Styled.ChatMessage>
              </Styled.MessageWrapper>
              <Styled.Status />
            </Styled.MessageFlexColumn>
          ) : (
          /*here is the bot messages*/
            <Styled.MessageFlexColumn key={index}>
              <Styled.MessageWrapper>
              <Styled.BotImg src={BotLogo} />
                <Styled.ChatMessage>
                <Styled.TypingWrapper show={isTyping}>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
              </Styled.TypingWrapper>
              {!isTyping ? rowData.text: ''}
              </Styled.ChatMessage>
              </Styled.MessageWrapper>
              <Styled.Status />
            </Styled.MessageFlexColumn>
          )
        )}
        <div ref={messagesEndRef} />
      </Styled.ChatLog>
 <Styled.ChatBox />
```

problem with gift:

[image]

basically all messages have typing animation when sending a new message
I don't know if I had the best logic with this code, basically I have an action to send the user's message to display in the chat message a wait_response action where I do this chat bot response handling

Comment: There is quite a bit to unpack in your code example, so you might try pairing it down to a minimal reproducible example, but if I had to guess I'd say that your chat typing state is derived from some piece of your redux state and that there is no individual state tracking whether the message has been sent. So when the redux state all components relying on it rerender.

Comment: ok i go edit question now, sorry.

Comment: basically I only use typing animation in my bot's response

I have an action when the user sends the text

and an action to set my state: waitMessage to true

so that I can do the typing effect

and an action for the bot's response

Comment: The answer I posted should point you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this in your bot component

```
const [hasResponded, setHasResponded] = useState(false);


 useEffect(() => {
    // Notice the change here checking if we have already responded
    // The if statement now surrounds the timeout and the interval
    // This prevents any of these actions from happening once the response  has been made
    if(ChatReducer.waitResponse === true && !hasResponded){ 
      setIsTyping(true);
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {have already responded
        setIsTyping(false);
        setHasResponded(true); // flag that this component has responded and need not perform these actions again
        dispatch(wait_end());
      }, 3000);
    }
    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }, [ChatReducer.waitResponse, hasResponded]);
```

Comment: this work on first time after second message dont work

Comment: because setHasResponded is true all time after second message and if I set it to false it will continue with the same problem

Comment: You need to refactor your Bot into its own component for this to work. It really needs to be its own component anyway.

Comment: Would you help me out of this? I'm confused